# PullRefreshLayout is blinking and freezing when RecyclerView has one more item then screen fits

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have some problems with pullrefresh layout animation. 
The thing is this issue is **relevant only** when there are **one more item in adapter than screen fits**.

I want to emphasys that if I **add one more** item to the list or **remove one item** pullDownToFerfesh **works perfectly**.
You can see the behavior in this [video](https://youtu.be/SYr4NCWTopY)

**UPDATE:**

I've checked if any tasks could be executed in UI thread, and I commented all callbacks and profiled UI thread and found out that only one operation takes time: Handler.dispatchMessage. No heavy calls of my code at all. 
This is my layout:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.timyo.andapp.ui.utils.AppBarLayoutBehavior">

         <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/tab_indicator_height"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="@dimen/tab_padding"
                app:tabPaddingStart="@dimen/tab_padding" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/messages_recycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

             </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: Can you paste codes here? My guess is, if the screen freeze, it is likely that you are doing some IO operation or some logics that takes time on UI thread. Generally speaking, move those tasks into another thread and update the UI once it is done.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. @hjchin good point, I updated my question but did find any heavy tasks executing in UI thread. Seems that it's a conflict between `CollapsingToolbar` and `PullDownToRefresh`

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if u have the code here, BUT i think i spot something in your xml

> ```
>         <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
>             android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>             android:id="@+id/messages_recycler"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

The closing tag of android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout is wrong.

Comment: Structure of layout is OK, I just missed this close tag when copied.

Comment: No, i meant you have a </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout> above 
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Comment: I got it, thank you. I edited the code snippet in the post.

Answer (score 0):

likely i solved this problem. So, problem was concerned to scroll toolbar behavior and swipe to refresh layout. Because once I remove `scrollFlags`(only for test) animation works OK.

I found the solution [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout). So I put `NestedScrollView` with content layout first in the `CoordinatorLayout` and then `AppBarLayout` with `TabLayout` and animation began work OK.

It's still unclear for me why it was relevant only with exact number of items, probably there are something connected to `interceptTouchEvent/onTouchEvent` calls.